# How do I print a result of JS function inside a twig loop

Tags: javascript, html, twig

I have two twig variables. I need to pass them to my js function travelTime()and return result in html-tag. 
Here is code. It is not works :

```
{% for item in trains %}
<div class="trainShedule">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div id="trainShedule-timeTravel">
                {% block javascripts %}
                    <script> travelTime('{{ item.departure.time }}', '{{ item.arrival.time }}' </script>
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}

<script>
    function travelTime(firstTime, secondTime){
        let getDate = (string) => new Date(0, 0,0, string.split(':')[0], string.split(':')[1]); 
        let different = (getDate(secondTime) - getDate(firstTime));
        let hours = Math.floor((different % 86400000) / 3600000);
        let minutes = Math.round(((different % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000);
        let result = hours + ':' + minutes;
        $(this)[0].innerHTML = result;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to render clear html, without implementing any javascript into your code.

Pass your variables to html-node attrs in twig loop and remove node's ids, use classes, like this:

```
 {% for item in trains %}
<div class="trainShedule">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="data_output" data-departure="{{ item.departure.time }}" data-arrival= "{{ item.arrival.time }}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

then improve ypur js like this:

```
<script>
    //you don't need params in your functions, we need to get data other way..
    function travelTime(){
        //collect nodes you want to add value
        let dataNodes = document.getElementsByClassName('data_output');

        //loop over dataNodes
        for(let i = 0; i < dataNodes.length; i++){

          //get current values for this node
          let departure = dataNodes[i].dataset.departure;
          let arrival = dataNodes[i].dataset.arrival;

          //here you do your mathematics stuff
          //.... result..

          //finally pass data to html-node          
          dataNodes[i].innerHTML = result;
        }
    }

    //don't forget to call function!
    travelTime();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<script>` tags are not scoped in the way you intend it to be. Instead, you should invert your approach:

1. Add the necessary metadata, such as `item.departure.time` and `item.arrival.time`, in HTML5 `data-` attributes, e.g. `data-departure-time="{{ item.departure.time}}"`.
2. Use JS to iterate through these elements and retrieve these metadata using [Element.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset). In each iteration, invoke your function `travelTime()` with the retrieved data, and then set the element's `innerText` to the return value. You can access the value of `data-departure-time` attribute using `Element.dataset.departureTime`, for example (note the kebab-case in your markup VS camel case in the JS)

p/s: Note that you should not use duplicate IDs, so I have changed it to using a class instead.

```
<div
    class="trainShedule-timeTravel"
    data-departure-time="{{ item.departure.time }}"
    data-arrival-time="{{ item.arrival.time }}">
```

Then, in your JS, simply iterate through all elements that matches the selector `.trainShedule-timeTravel`:

```
function travelTime(firstTime, secondTime){
    let getDate = (string) => new Date(0, 0,0, string.split(':')[0], string.split(':')[1]); 
    let different = (getDate(secondTime) - getDate(firstTime));
    let hours = Math.floor((different % 86400000) / 3600000);
    let minutes = Math.round(((different % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000);
    let result = hours + ':' + minutes;

    return result;
}

const els = document.querySelectorAll('.trainShedule-timeTravel');
Array.from(els).forEach(el => {
    el.innerText = travelTime(el.dataset.departureTime, el.dataset.arrivalTime);
});
```